# Android - Material Theme - Change colorAccent for just active tab

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Here is my custom theme file:

```
<style name="MyMaterial" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#4CAF50</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4CAF50</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

The problem is, I want #FFFFFF only for the active tab underline (like yellow in [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-V5zTYl_bx1U/VIbllhK1UFI/AAAAAAAARSk/4vGtfKyva8g/s1600/device-2014-12-09-210031.png)), but not the other controls such as checkbox activated. What is the best/proper way of doing this?

Side questions:
- The default tabs have vertical dividers. How to remove them like the picture above?
- How to add shadow beneath tabs like the picture above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), part of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) takes the tab indicator color from `colorAccent`, but you can also use `app:tabIndicatorColor` to set a different color specifically on the `TabLayout` (and not include yellow as your accent color in your theme):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

`TabLayout does not have any separator lines, as per the [material design spec][3]. The shadow is added via elevation - if you include your`TabLayout` in your [AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) you'll get elevation on Android 5.0 and higher devices.

Comment: Where should I put the above code? My theme file is under /res/values/.

Comment: In your layout that includes a `TabLayout` - be sure to read the blog post linked around using the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) if you aren't using it already.